# How to create array from computed property array field in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a computed property that pulls some data out of my vuex store like so:

`computed: {...mapGetters(["allCategories"])},`

Each `category` in `this.allCategories` looks like so:

`{ "id":  "123", "name": "Foo" }`

I want to pull out every `name` field from `this.allCategories` before the component is mounted in put each `name` into an reactive data property called `categoryNames`.

How can I achieve this?

What I have tried so far is below:

```
beforeMount() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.allCategories.content.length; i++) {
      var name = this.allCategories.content[i].name
      this.categoryNames.push(name);
    }
},
```

Which gives the following error:

```
 Error in beforeMount hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"
```

`this.allCategories` looks like so:

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": "efb038df-4bc9-4e31-a37a-e805c9d7294e",
            "parentCategoryId": "8ffc214f-fff1-4433-aac9-34d13b4e06c5",
            "name": "Foo"
        },
        {
            "id": "5905d437-db2e-4f91-8172-c515577b86e9",
            "parentCategoryId": "5905d437-db2e-4f91-8172-c515577b86e9",
            "name": "Bar"
        },
        {
            "id": "8ffc214f-fff1-4433-aac9-34d13b4e06c5",
            "parentCategoryId": "8ffc214f-fff1-4433-aac9-34d13b4e06c5",
            "name": "Baz"
        }
    ],
    "number": 0,
    "size": 100,
    "total": 3
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the created hook to call a vuex action that calls a vuex mutation that grabs a state, do your parsing and store the parsed data in a new array in state, then use a getter to grab the parsed array from state.

```
created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('someAction');
},
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
        parsedArray: 'getParsedArray',
    })
}
```

```
export const actions = {
    someAction({ commit }) {
        commit('SOME_MUTATION');
    },
}
```

```
export const mutations = {

  SOME_MUTATION(state) {
    let data = state.originalData;
     let parsedArray = [];

    // Do parsing work here

    state.parsedArray = parsedArray
  },

}
```

```
export const getters = {
  getParsedArray: state => {
    return state.parsedArray;
  },
}
```